# Is it ok to fully clone into SSD (NVMe)?

Tags: linux, ssd, dd, disk-cloning, nvme

I've read somewhere that a good rule of thumb is to keep your partitions/solid drives 50% full to have prolonged life.

Now, I just bought an NVMe and I'm cloning my main drive in there (is going to be a 1:1 copy).

Is that a wise thing to do durability wise?
The partitions from the disk I'm cloning are less than 30% full and I wonder if by using *dd* I would mistakenly fill up the NVMe, thus reducing its performance and tear?

Am I completely wrong? I hope so...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using an up to date operating system then it should enabled for [TRIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trim_(computing)) and you should also be able to issue TRIM manually.

Writing the entire drive might via `dd` might inadvertently cause the wear leveller to believe the entire drive is used. You are correct that this is not necessarily a great thing.

Which isn't really a problem because you can force all the free space to be trimmed again and the worst that happens is that you've used up a write cycle for most of the flash cells for the drive. (There are other tools which might not copy every byte 1:1 but only the used blocks). This can be scheduled to regularly happen and keep the drive firmware aware of all the blocks that can be cleaned up during slow time.

You can also enable blocks to be released whenever a file is deleted.

According to [Arch Linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Solid_state_drive) you should prefer to use one or the other of these methods rather than both, with periodic trim being preferred.

Periodic

> The `util-linux` package provides `fstrim.service` and `fstrim.timer`
>   `systemd` unit files. Enabling the timer will activate the service
>   weekly. The service executes `fstrim(8)` on all mounted filesystems on
>   devices that support the *discard* operation.
>
> The timer relies on the timestamp of
>   `/var/lib/systemd/timers/stamp-fstrim.timer` (which it will create upon
>   first invocation) to know whether a week has elapsed since it last
>   ran. Therefore there is no need to worry about too frequent
>   invocations, in an anacron-like fashion.
>
> To query the units activity and status, see `journalctl`. To change the
>   periodicity of the timer or the command run, edit the provided unit
>   files.

Continuous

> Using the `discard` option for a mount in `/etc/fstab` enables continuous
>   TRIM in device operations:
>
> ```
> /dev/sda1  /           ext4  defaults,discard   0  1
> ```

If you, or rather your distribution, have set up periodic `trim` then a short time after you copy it then `trim` should be issued for all the empty blocks and everything should be hunky dory.

Comment: Thanks! I have done something else, which is written very large zero files to almost fill up the space and then I removed those. Also I'll check the fstab to ensure discard is enabled. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.3 with HWE (kernel 5+).

Comment: Yep, Ubuntu also does a weekly trim. I guess I forced one now, after deleting the large files, everything should be ok going forward!

Comment: I know many older SSDs did effectively TRIM when seeing data that is entirely zero, but yeah, that is another way to do it.

Comment: I've read about the TRIM specification, the sources of fstrim, and the FITRIM ioctl, and I feel dumb. I should have just had to issue a fstrim command after cloning and that would have been it, no need to fill up NAND space and waste 1 more P/E cycle.

Comment: @Emanuele I don't think you *would* have wasted another P/E cycle. Sure manually triggering a trim would have done the job in one shot, but a lot of old devices (which lacked trim) used a zerofill to effectively tell the device that those blocks could be freed up and had tools to do as much. I'd be surprised if that wasn't still kept as part of the firmware functionality in order to allow older systems that don't support trim to do the same job by a user manually zeroing empty blocks. I don't think you actually wasted a P/E cycle, just went a roundabout way of telling the drive to issue TRIM.

Comment: Thanks for the encouraging reply, though I have done this to a 970 EVO 1 TB M.2, fairly recent piece of hardware. I do hope they have implemented what you describe, but I feel I have wasted a P/E cycle! Well, silver lining I guess thanks to opensource and Linux I managed to understand what I did wrong and I'm less ignorant now! :-)

Comment: Yeah, looking at it again, what I thought was true the internet seems to deny... so I may be wrong. But as you say we live and learn. It's not a massive loss in the long term.